# Reference for guided exercises in Group Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

im sorry if this is recurrent, but i searched the site and didn't find anything that suited my question.

I'm an engineering grad student, and in my spare time i study abstract algebra on my own. I'm using Serge Lang Algebraic Structures for a start. I found it a really tight and informative book, not too formal neither too loose, and i can get through the text and understand most of the theorems proofs. But when it comes to exercises i find it too hard, most of the times i struggle to even start a question. And also, there is no answers or guidance whatsoever. So my question is, where can i find exercises with some kind of resolution or answers, because as i said, i study on my own so there isnt anyone to check my stuff for me.

Right now i'm at a really beginner level, isomorphisms, subgroups, cosets and automorphisms. I don't want to continue before i'm sure i get those concepts well, and in my opinion no one gets math just by reading.
Thank you.

Comment: Bhattacharya's Basic abstract algebra (second edition) is a great book with many exercises solved and a "really tight and informative book, not too formal neither too loose". I hope this will be useful.

Comment: Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra* has a lot of nice exercises which are elementary but also interesting. Some of them develop examples which help to illustrate the definitions, some establish basic consequences of the definitions, and others allow you to prove new theorems, in a step-by-step fashion that makes it all very accessible to the beginner. He includes answers and hints for selected exercises.

Comment: Thanks guys, i will check out those recommendations.

Comment: Have a look at Joseph Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra. It contains solutions to all odd numbered problems.